How could Rachel Imeinu have revealed Yaakov's secret to Leah?
The Orchos Chaim L'Rosh (41) writes:

סוֹד אַחֵר אַל תְּגַל. גַּם אֶת הַדְּבָרִים אֲשֶּׁר יְדַבְּרוּ
לְפָנֶיךָ שֶּׁלֹּא עַל דֶּרֶךְ סוֹד, טוֹמְנֵהוּ בְּקִירוֹת לִבֶּךָ -
Do not reveal the secrets of others. Even non-confidential matters,
keep in the confines of your heart.

The Chafetz Chaim paskens (Rechilus 8:5:7)

וְחַיָּב אָדָם לְהַסְתִּיר הַסוֹד, אֲשֶׁר יְגַלֶּה לוֹ חֲבֵרוֹ דֶּרֶךְ
סֵתֶר, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵין בְּגִלּוּי הַסוֹד הַהוּא עִנְיַן
רְכִילוּת, כִּי יֵשׁ בְּגִלּוּי הַסוֹד נֵזֶק לִבְעָלָיו וְסִבָּה
לְהָפֵר מַחֲשַׁבְתּוֹ, גַּם בָּזֶה הוּא יוֹצֵא מִדֶּרֶךְ הַצְּנִיעוּת,
וְהוּא מַעֲבִיר עַל דַּעַת בַּעַל הַסּוֹד - And a man must conceal a
secret which his friend tells him in private, even though there is no
rechilus in the revelation of this secret. For there is in its
revelation harm to its confider and cause for voidance of his plans.
Also, in this ["dust" of rechilus], he departs from the way of modesty
and transgresses the will of his confidant.

How could Rachel Imeinu have revealed the secret simanim Yaakov Avinu gave her to ensure Lavan did not switch her with Leah? See Rashi Bereishis (29:25)

ויהי בבקר והנה היא לאה. אֲבָל בַּלַּיְלָה לֹא הָיְתָה לֵאָה, לְפִי
שֶׁמָּסַר יַעֲקֹב סִימָנִים לְרָחֵל, וּכְשֶׁרָאֲתָה רָחֵל
שֶׁמַּכְנִיסִין לוֹ לֵאָה אָמְרָה: עַכְשָׁו תִּכָּלֵם אֲחוֹתִי,
עָמְדָה וּמָסְרָה לָהּ אוֹתָן סִימָנִים (מגילה י"ג):  ויהי בבקר והנה
הוא לאה AND IT CAME TO PASS, THAT IN THE MORNING, BEHOLD, IT WAS LEAH
— But at night it was not Leah (i. e. he failed to recognise that it
was Leah) because Jacob had given Rachel certain secret signs by which
they could at all times recognise one another, and when Rachel saw
that they were about to bring Leah to him for the marriage ceremony,
she thought, “My sister may now be put to shame”, and she therefore
readily transmitted these signs to her (Megillah 13b).


The citations are a little irrelevant. Obviously she violated his trust, but she didn't reveal secrets in the sense of private information. A secret code is just an authentication mechanism.

@shmosel The citation from the Chafetz Chayyim is absolutely relevant: כִּי יֵשׁ בְּגִלּוּי הַסוֹד נֵזֶק לִבְעָלָיו וְסִבָּה לְהָפֵר מַחֲשַׁבְתּוֹ. This is exactly what she did with the "authentication mechanism."

I'm thinking the answer could be she was allowed to do it in order to avoid embarrassing Leah: אמרה השתא מיכספא אחתאי (Megilla 13b)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In the book Bedarchei Avot Khelek 2, pg 357, Rabbi Aharon pessin shlit"a brings from the kol simkha that what Rakhel did was an aveira lishma


It wasn't a secret in the sense that it was information about himself that he didn't want revealed to others. It was a secret code that he gave her to use to identify herself. Once he gave it to her, it was hers to use. It now belonged to her and she in her infinite wisdom and compassion decided to share it with Leah. This resulted in 6 Shevatim being born out of the 12 that were destined. BTW - I recently saw that the secret code was either touching his right earlobe, right thumb and right big toe, or citing the mitzvahs of women of Challah, Niddah and Lighting candles.
Also BTW- your question might have been better asked as to how she could be Gonev Daas to Yaacov as opposed to Loshen Hara. In either case, the answer will be that she saw/knew with Ruach Hakodesh that this was supposed to be her destiny. We are mere mortals. The Imuhos and the Avos were on a different plane of existence.

The Chafetz Chayyim quoted in the question already says it's not rechilut, but it's still forbidden. As you yourself note towards the end of your answer, the question might have been asked by presenting it as genevat daat. But then your answer to that is just saying that she somehow knew with ruach hakodesh, which doesn't explain what her decision was based on.

I hear. One more comment. The Avos kept the Torah even Eruv Tafshilim (or another Gersa Eruvei Techumin), of Shabbos as the Midrash says. But some say only in Chutz L'Aretz. This was not in the Holy Land and that's why he was able to marry two sisters and why Rochel passed away in Beth Lechem and only then did Yaacov enter the Holy Land.

Bethlehem isn't the holy land?

That is a great question! Yes, Beth Lechem is part of biblical Israel. One answer might be they were married in Haran which was in Turkey or maybe bordering Syria. So, the original marriage was not prohibited outside of Eretz Yisroel.

But then you may ask, how could he stay married to her once he entered EY if Beth Lechem was in EY  and what does it mean that she died outside of EY? As you know, Rochel died giving birth to Benyomin. So, likely they did not have marital relations for a while before that. (? Not sure this is adequate answer). But I rechecked the Rambam who gives this answer, and I correct my previous answer. He says she died soon after entering Ey so Yaacov would not violate the prohibition against marrying two sisters.
